# How to follow links on a SPECIFIC webpage and analyse them recursively to download files using wget?

Tags: wget

I am trying to download audio files from a webpage using wget. I cannot get the command right.
Let us say the files are on the page http://songs.com/artists/name/album/2020
On this page there are several albums each has its own link that leads you to another page where the links to the audio files exist. The links for these audio files might lead to another website, for e.g. http://music.com/song.mp3
I want wget to ONLY download the 2020 albums and place each album (i.e. link) on a separate file.

Comment: I'm not sure what do you mean by "ONLY download the 2020 albums and place each album (i.e. link) on a separate file". Wget is meant to re-create the structure of the webpage you are downloading, ie. you will start from main "2020" page, where you will have links to album pages, and from these pages links to audio files. Wget will download all these pages and audio files. There is no way to download only the audio files and skip the web pages, if that's what you want. You must write a separate script to do this.

Comment: What I meant is that wget is downloading things that I don't want to download. For e.g 2019 albums which is on a different link. Regarding only downloading audio files my understanding is that adding - A mp3 will only download mp3 files.

Comment: So probably the page http://songs.com/artists/name/album/2020 , or any of the linked subpages, contains links to 2019 albums, otherwise wget wouldn't be able to find and download them. Without knowing the exact URLs, it is hard to say if there is any method to filter them out.